# Flysystem S3 remote file download always corrupted

Tags: php, zend-framework2, middleware, flysystem, psr-7

I recently started using Flysystem in an existing application with the intention of abstracting the local and remote (specifically, S3) filesystems. Everything was working ok on my development environment, on which I successfully configured the LocalAdapter. However, I cannot get S3 file downloads to work. I'd like to point out that file uploads are working perfectly, given that I can successfully download the file by manually browsing the S3 bucket in the AWS management console. That being said, I will skip the code that initializes the `$filesystem` variable.

My application is using a PSR-7 approach. That is, the code below is inside a function that is passed an object of type `Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface` as first argument and an object of type `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` as the second. Given that the local filesystem works fine, I think it is safe to assume that the problem doesn't lie there.

This is the code:

```
<?php

    $stream = new \Zend\Diactoros\Stream($filesystem->readStream($filename));
    $filesize = $stream->getSize();

    return $response
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
            ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'Binary')
            ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
            ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
            ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
            ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate')
            ->withHeader('Content-Length', "{$filesize}")
            ->withBody($stream);
```

When I dump the `$stream` variable and the `$filesize` variable the results are as expected. The remote file contents are successfully printed. However, the file download is always corrupted and the file size is always of 0 bytes.

I am assuming that Flysystem takes care of everything behind the scenes and that I don't have to manually download the file to a temp folder first, before serving it to the client.

Any clue to what could be the problem?

**Update 1**

I have also tried with the following code, without any luck. However, it continues to work locally:

```
use Zend\Diactoros\CallbackStream;

$stream = new CallbackStream(function() use ($filesystem, $filename) {
     $resource = $filesystem->readStream($filename);
     while (!feof($resource)) {
         echo fread($resource, 1024);
     }
     fclose($resource);
     return '';
});
```

and

```
use Zend\Diactoros\CallbackStream;

$stream = new CallbackStream(function() use ($filesystem, $filename) {
     $resource = $filesystem->readStream($filename);
     fpassthru($resource);
     return '';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Content-Length header seems to solve the problem.

See https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/543 for more details.